# Computation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to get the results of a calculation in a stored procedure which admits only one parameter ("code") in example.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure Test(in code varchar(8)) language sql deterministic
begin
set @sql=concat("select (a+b+c) as N, (d+e+f) as D from Tbl where code='",code,"'");
set r=N/D;
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
set @age=@NUM/@DEN;
end$$
```

I would like to get N, D and r.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you might solve your problem more easily with a view instead of a stored procedure. You could, for example define the view

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS
SELECT *,N/D r FROM (select code, a+b+c N, d+e+f D FROM tmp) sub;
```

When you use that in a `SELECT` then you can easily filter for the `code` you are interested in, like

```
SELECT * from testview WHERE code='yourcode'
```

You will then get a result like

```
code      N    D   r
yourcode  468  234 2
```

The view can of course be used in connection with other, more complex queries or subqueries.

**Edit:**
As hinted by Paul the view will be much more effective if written without the use of a subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW testview AS
SELECT code, a+b+c N, d+e+f D, (a+b+c)/(d+e+f) r  FROM tmp;
```

Comment: Why the subquery? `(a+b+c) / (d+e+f) as r` should be fine.

Comment: Int or float ... And the divison could be another operation for ex. (a + b +c)/sqr(d+e+f)

Comment: @Paul Spiegel: I assumed that OP wanted to get all three values:`D`, `N` and `r`. The subquery enables me to get all these values without doing a calculation twice.

Comment: Using a subquery means generating an unfiltered temporary table. That is probabably worse than calculating some values twice because usually I/O matters more than CPU-Time.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel: OK, thanks, point taken! So: the purpose is served better with a flat query ;-)